# Simple multiplication

Tags: c#, .net

Let's get straight to the point. I made the following code to multiply two numbers and it's "eating" my zeroes! It seems to work fine for cases which don't involve having a product (p) that is equal to zero. In the sample case it simply prints "5" instead of the desired "500". I'd be really thankful if anyone cared to explain what's going on. :)

```
using System;
class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(smallNumBigNumProduct("5", "100"));
   }

   static string smallNumBigNumProduct(string s, string b)
   {
      int l = s.Length;
      int f = int.Parse(s); // factor
      int c = 0; // carry
      string r = ""; // result
      int p; // product

      while(l-- > 0)
       {
          p = (Convert.ToInt32(b[l]) - 48) * f;
          p += c;

          if (p > 9)
          {
            r = Convert.ToString(p % 10) + r;
            c = p / 10;
          }

          else
            r = Convert.ToString(p) + r;
       }

       if (c > 0)
       {
         r = Convert.ToString(c) + r;
       }

   return r;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. :p

Comment: Oops... I just saw my mistake.

Comment: One letter variable names hurt you *and* me.

Comment: Nice use of the "goes to operator". :-) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/01/somelastminutefeatures.aspx

Comment: @Eric: I didn't even realize that the operator still works even with a space in it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
int l = s.Length;

...

while(l-- > 0)
```

You are setting your `l` variable to the length of the *short* string, then in your `while` loop you pre-decrement it.

In short, your loop isn't executed the number of times you think it is. Shouldn't the `l` variable be set to the length of the `b` string?

Regardless, this looks like a long and error prone way to do this. Why not simply convert the input strings to integers and return the product directly?

Comment: I already fixed this mistake! I meant to use b, not l. Slight oversight! Thanks! The reason I'm doing it this way is to be able to multiply a small number with one that has tens of digits.

Comment: So, the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) introduced in .NET 4.0 can't work for you?

Comment: I'm using this for a SPOJ problem, not sure if I can use BigInteger over there.

Comment: @Codetester - Sounds like the kind of constraint you should have mentioned in your question. Explaining _why_ you have to write such code will help with getting appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
    public static string smallNumBigNumProduct(string a, string b)
    {
          // NOTE no error checking for bad input or possible overflow...

        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(a);
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(b);

        return ((num1*num2).ToString());
    }
```

Or even better if you are using .NET 4.0 (updated thanks to Gabe's prompting):

```
public static string smallNumBigNumProduct(string a, string b)
{
    // NOTE no error checking for bad input or possible overflow...

    BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.Zero;
    BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.Zero;

    bool convert1 = BigInteger.TryParse(a, out num1);
    bool convert2 = BigInteger.TryParse(b, out num2);

    return (convert1 && convert2) ? (num1*num2).ToString() : "Unable to convert";
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that a function with "BigNum" in its name can be implemented with just `Convert.ToInt32`? I mean, you'd at least want to use `long` or `decimal`. Not mention which, even the `BigInteger` solution is broken because it converts to `Int64` before doing the multiply.